# ReactiveUI: Why do I have to specify the scheduler explicitly in "...Throttle..."when using the TestScheduler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reactiveui

I'm new to ReactiveUI. I have the following simple setup: a path to a csv can be specified and the containing datapoints will be displayed to the user (using oxyplot).
Now I'm trying to test the following subscription:

```cs
public GraphViewModel(IScreen hostScreen)
{
   HostScreen = hostScreen;

   setupGraphFormatting();

   // Data Loading if path is valid
   this.WhenAnyValue(viewModel => viewModel.PathToDataCsv)
      .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
      .Select(csvPath => csvPath?.Trim('"'))
      .Where(csvPath => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvPath) && File.Exists(csvPath))
      .Subscribe(csvPath =>
      {
         csvPath = csvPath?.Trim('"');
         updatePlotModel(csvPath);
      }, exception => {});

   /* additional Code*/
}
```

And that's the corresponding UnitTest:

```cs
[Test]
public void If_PathToDataCsv_has_a_valid_value()
{
   new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
   {
      string pathToValidCsvFile = "data.log";
      var viewModel = new GraphViewModel(null);

      scheduler.AdvanceByMs(1000);

      viewModel.PathToDataCsv = pathToValidCsvFile;

      scheduler.AdvanceByMs(1000);

      viewModel.PlotModel.Series.Count.Should().Be(6);
   });
}
```

My first implementation of WhenAnyValue didn't set any of the Schedulers specifically ( in Throttle and lacking any ObserverOn ):

```cs
public GraphViewModel(IScreen hostScreen)
{
   HostScreen = hostScreen;

   setupGraphFormatting();

   // Data Loading if path is valid
   this.WhenAnyValue(viewModel => viewModel.PathToDataCsv)
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
      .Select(csvPath => csvPath?.Trim('"'))
      .Where(csvPath => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvPath) && File.Exists(csvPath))
      .Subscribe(csvPath =>
      {
         csvPath = csvPath?.Trim('"');
         updatePlotModel(csvPath);
      }, exception => {});

   /* additional Code*/
}
```

But then my Unittest failed. My assumption was that TestScheduler was being used for Throttle behind the scenes and I didn't have to do anything. Am I doing something wrong or is this the right way: If I want to use TestScheduler/TimeTravel™ I have to specify the schedulers the way I did?

**Edit in response to Glenn Watsons answer:** 
Ok, now it's clear: The methods in question (Throttle, ObserverOn) of course do not use ReactiveUI's Schedulers, because these are methods from the Reactive Extensions Framework. So they can't be replaced implicitly by ReactiveUI in case of a UnitTest except I tell the methods to use the RxApp Schedulers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxApp provides the ThreadPoolScheduler when you are in release mode, and the testing scheduler when you are in unit test mode.

By default the reactive extensions (separate to ReactiveUI) will use their own default schedulers which are unaware of unit tests.